# What type/model of plane is this?

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image: Photo of right side of cockpit, above and below wind screen]

I came across this photo but it doesn't have any other info. What type of plane is it? Also, is it some sort of seaplane perhaps? I say seaplane because it was tagged with the word "seaplane". Seems Cessna-ish to me but I'm clueless beyond that. Is it possible to identify the exact model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a Cessna 208 Caravan to me:

[image]
[image]

These are single-engine high-wing turboprops, useful for a variety of cargo and passenger-hauling tasks. Here's what a 208 in seaplane configuration looks like on the outside:

[image]

Your photo looks like an older plane with the original radio stack and no glass, unlike these newer cockpits. In addition, somewhat startlingly, the right-hand control column and yoke have been removed, but they bothered to keep the copilot's 6-pack. That's odd, from my sensibilities, and it tells me the plane was altered in the cheapest possible way for use as a pure short-range passenger ferry. The right-hand seat can now accomodate an extra passenger (and becomes the best in the house for enjoying the view), without the possibility of that non-flier binding up the pilot's controls.

Comment: Would they be removed if it's used for "tourists"?

Comment: See my edit; I thought of that after I posted the original. Still somewhat odd, though more sensible if the pilot is spending his days taking groups of people on pleasure hops around a lagoon or bay. The front seat is now an extra paying passenger who can't inadvertently bind you up while twisting around his seat to get pictures. Doesn't appear to be illegal, but it limits the utility of the plane for tasks beyond air tours.

Comment: I did find the photo posted by a tourist I think.  So curious how you narrowed down which Cessna it was? ☺

Comment: I took a guess (I agreed it'd likely be a Cessna, as most seaplanes are high-wing), and searched Google Images for "Cessna Seaplane cockpit", then scanned that for images with similar panel configurations on the copilot side, and found a few definitively identified as the 208. A slightly wider search of similarly-sized models shows that 6-pack on the copilot's side to be a pretty dead giveaway; most other 100s and 200s have a pretty spartan right-hand panel, while the panels for twins in the 300/400 levels tend to have a more beveled corner (and many more gauges for multi-engine monitoring).

Comment: Can it land in water?

Comment: Of course; those big long hull sections under the fuselage in that last picture aren't for decoration.

Comment: Lol, I don't know how I missed that!  